# Does WCF (dotnet 4) require webHttpBinding to be able to easily return JSON?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, air, wcf-binding

My service will be consumed by another application on the same box (Adobe AIR as it happens), and I can't run a server. I'm currently running a WCF service as a Windows service on the box to achieve this. No server means no REST (please do correct me if I'm wrong with any of this), but I still want my service to be able to return JSON.

I've been doing research on this, and finding lots of people using REST services with webHttpBinding and then setting a JSON behaviour in the config, however for reasons above I believe I can't use REST.

So with that as a background, my question is: Can a WCF service running as either basicHttpBinding, or WSHttpBinding (would like to avoid due to the overheads) return JSON without me having to hand roll it?

If so, would someone be good enough to explain how?

Here are the current details of my app.config for the service

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfProjectLibrary.ProjectService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfProjectLibrary.IProjectService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfProjectLibrary/ProjectService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>-->
<behaviors>      
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />          
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON can be returned only with `webHttpBinding` or custom binding using same binding elements as `webHttpBinding` and you can still host REST (with `webHttpBinding`) service in windows service. `WebHttpBinding` together with `WebHttpBehavior` are responsible for correct processing of non-SOAP messages.

I have no idea what you mean by no server. Process exposing the service is "a server" in terms of communication. You just need full .NET framework 4 (client profile is not enough) and http.sys installed (you will need it with any HTTP based binding).

Comment: Thank you for your response. My understanding was that a REST endpoint could only be delivered via a web server, whereas my WCF service is running as a Windows service. You have cleared this up for me, thank you very much!

Comment: It offers more functionality on web server because some features are related to ASP.NET but core functionality can be still delivered with self-hosting in any .NET process.

Comment: I can't reach the REST endpoint, I've edited my question to show my current app.config. I don't have an svc file, as the WCF project didn't create one for me. Do I need to create this myself in order to be able to have a contactable end point?

Comment: You said you don't want to host it in web server but your service is running in test web server and you are obviously developing it for web server hosting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: No, I have installed this service as a windows service. I can browse to the endpoint specified as the base address (which defaults to SOAP), and my test client can consume the service effectively. I'm using installutil to install the service. I am as surprised as you are that this works inside a Windows service.

Comment: Your service didn't run in test server but in test host. Make sure that it really works.

Comment: I had to change the config file back to as above, but I can confirm that this works as a SOAP service from a Windows service. My test client can call and receive data from the service. Can I turn this into a REST endpoint using the method you have described above?